# Can i use conditional statements in cartodb?

Tags: carto

I want to code my Cartodb.js map so that for each marker, if a column is not empty, it embeds a video into the infowindow, and if the column is empty, then it does noting.I saw this example online and tried to copy it, but it didn't work. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

for my code, inside the {{content}} area, I said: 
if ({{video_embed_link}} IS NOT NULL) {< iframe width="430" height="242" src="{{video_embed_link}}" frameborder="0"> < /iframe>}

any suggestions on what to do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infowindows use Mustache templates, which don't allow for logic. You can do it with SQL(1) and some cleverness

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  CASE WHEN video_embed_link null THEN 0 ELSE 242 END AS video_height
FROM 
  table_name
```

Then, in your template, just do

```
< iframe width="430" height="{{video_height}}" src="{{video_embed_link}}" frameborder="0"> < /iframe>
```

Now, the iframe should be 0 pixels high if the embed link is NULL

*1. I tend to say SQL can solve anything*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple CSS based solution which will work for iframes, images, links.

```
iframe[src=""],img[src=""],a[href=""] {
   display:none;
}
```